# How to stop an eventListener from being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angular, event-listener

I have added an eventListener and is being called multiple times. Is there any way to call it only once?

Here is my code snippet.

```
  this.elements.on('done', function (event) {
  console.log(event);
})
```

Comment: Do you use `jquery` with `angular`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Angular you should really look into [rxjs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library).
However, for the provided code snippet, a simple solution would be:

```
const handled = false;
this.elements.on('done', function (event) {
  if (!handled) {
     // do things
     handled = true;
  }
})
```